Site may not be described as "LEGO Answers" - call for alternative titles
UPDATE: After a further review in March 2017, TLG have confirmed that they would like us to change the site name. This post is kept for reference.

I've got this comment from Jan Beyer, Community Operations Manager for the LEGO Group:

Regarding the website - it should not be called LEGO Answers - this imply that the LEGO Group answers but perhaps "Answers regarding LEGO bricks".

Now I have to admit I can't really find the part of the site which says "LEGO Answers", as everywhere I look I see "LEGO® — Stack Exchange" which may be OK; but if it does exist, can it be changed somehow?

Edit to add:
The site still has <title>LEGO® - Stack Exchange</title>, and so appears as "LEGO® - Stack Exchange" in Google results, and the mobile site also still has the main page heading as "LEGO®"

Follow-up:
LEGO Legal Affairs reviewed LEGO Answers and did not cite any problems with the name. They made a few suggestions about improving the site description to bring it into compliance. So, unless we hear otherwise, the site name does not need to be changed. 

The giant logo on the top left of the page reads "LEGO Answers"

Then that's probably what he was talking about. No idea why I still don't see it — I just see a blue "LEGO®" with a small red "beta" above.

It was changed last week, you may need to refresh in some fashion.

@Grace actually, I see "LEGO Answers" with Safari, and just "LEGO" with firefox... any idea why? Which one is the current one?

@Joe thanks, I tried to hit refresh in IE and saw "LEGO Answers" replace "LEGO" so you're certainly correct.

Could someone re-title this question so its more obvious it is the "name this site" question?

I love the fact that we can't have "LEGO" anywhere in our title, yet some upstart pop-boy can release a single called "LEGO House", without the capitalisation or anything ;) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4BLVznuWnU

Jan referred me to someone from LEGO Legal Affairs who took a look at the site and did not cite a problem with the name of the site. He made a few suggestions about improving the site description to bring it into compliance. So, unless we hear otherwise, the site name does not need to be changed.

Good to hear! Out of curiosity, did they comment on the content of the site so far?

@Robert Am I correct in hearing that the Lego bricks community is discouraged from discussing/voting/choosing the site's name? I seem to remember other communities getting to pick their name. What's different with this site?

@antony.trupe: Sites have not picked custom names for a very long time. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/

@Robert Fair enough, however, lego<-answers>.stackexchange.com doesn't exist, so I'm seeing inconsistency in the SE team's position. According to the blog post, the site name should match its domain, which in this case is bricks, right?

It's not a duplicate per-say but it's close enough. TLG originally accepted our name, but now that we're a Registered Media Fan Site we've been asked to change.

Brick Overflow
This has been brought up time and time again. The main reason for not calling the site Brick Overflow is that it's an in joke, and people who don't know about Stack Overflow will be confused, and hence not participate on the site, or something.
I disagree, I think it has a clear meaning in context to the site ("I have so many brick-related toys that they're overflowing everywhere!"). If you do know about Stack Overflow, there's an added bonus. Serenity was a great film, and I have friends who enjoyed watching it who had no idea Firefly existed. It still made sense on its own.

It sounds perfect

Well, to this specific questions, Jan answered:

I would like to see anything without LEGO.

So there. I'm in favour of "Brick (anything)". Even "overflow", while an in-joke, has a nice ring to it - who wouldn't be like to be overflown by bricks?

This isn't really a crowd-sourcing type of situation. We will talk to the folks over at LEGO® to see what, if anything, needs to be done to bring the site into compliance. But we're not really in search of a branded or customized name apart from LEGO® Bricks or LEGO® <something>… whatever will bring the trademark use into compliance.

I think contacts should indeed better be had at an admin level. Do you have any contact person already? If there are talks in progress, maybe this question ought to be closed.

Choosing a site name is not something the community does?

@Joubarc: My next task was to get in touch with you to get the contact you mentioned above. Would it be possible for you to forward an email to me to facilitate an introduction? community@stackexchange.com. Thanks.

I imagine the community can't pick a site name because there could be legal ramifications if the owner of the Lego trademark doesn't like it.

Robert, while I think it might be great to have "LEGO" in the title, how would that impact us answering questions on non-LEGO brick toys on the site (minority though they may be)? Equally, if the community is happy without the "LEGO" doesn't that make this moot?

@JoeWreschnig That's the problem with jumping into a conversation late in the game. I assumed it was the other way around. Thanks for the info.

Agreed - is there any news on this one way or another?

Still nothing to report?

LEGO's legal department didn't have a problem with the name of the site, but they made some suggestions to improve the wording around the various descriptions and such. With these minor changes, we are in compliance.

Cheers for the update :)

disappointed we don't get to talk about it :( might even say disenfranchised with the SE team.

Brick Stack
Sort of associates itself with the stack exchange network

Bricks
clean, simple, vague, open-ended.

Not to mention "bricks" is already in the URL and so it seems to make sense to include it in the site name.

Brick Answers
It is what it is.

Brick Q&A
Pretty clear its a Q&A site.

I'm pretty sure that as long as the word "lego" is not in the web address, it should be OK.

Brick Smarter
LEGO and other SAR toys
Trying to keep the tagline underneath from being really long like the following example:
Brick Smarter
Unofficial answers regarding LEGO bricks and other SAR toys
See how just trying to keep the tagline shorter helps the logo seem more coherent? I realize that the point is to "not be associated with LEGO", but then again I presume that other toys, such as DUPLO (another LEGO property) and K'Nex, fishertechnik, Mega bloks and similar toys are going to be asked here.
But yes, the LEGO brand is the most popular and is going to be the point of the most traffic for that reason.

That's funny, they look just like (ok, not quite, but assume the eyes of an eight year old) Technik. So Technik is OK but K'Nex isn't? Interesting isn't it? And if K'Nex is permitted, then so should be fischertechnik. Anyways, that's not my quibble. My point was "this site won't just be for LEGO brand toys will it?"

PS: SAR = Some Assembly Required. The "Brick Smarter" and the LEGO reference should help people figure out this isn't just for random toys that have to be put together when you get them home. I mean, I could see where there are people that slow in the world, but .. the title as "Brick ________" should help them figure it out.

Brick smarts is cute too.

@jcolebrand see this question here: http://meta.bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/38/lego-brick-based-toys-only

Brick Pile
Sounds like a sales site's name.

Mega Bloks
And other building block systems

Heh. Is that the sound of sharpening pitchforks I can hear? ;)

Hang on, I think I can hear it too!

Name alternatives:

Answers regarding LEGO bricks
Bricks
Brick Overflow
Brick Exchange
Brick Pile
Brick Answers
Brick Q&A
Brick Stack
Stack Brick
Stack OverBrick
MegaBlok Answers
Unofficial LEGO Answers (Unofficial answers regarding LEGO bricks)


@JoeWreschnig can I ask why?

I thought maybe you had a more firm reason why the last one was unacceptable in the shorter form. All LEGO wanted was that the name not imply that they were answering questions

@JoeWreschnig It has Answers as a friend.

what does that mean? I'm confused. "should never stand alone" ... huh?

@jcolebrand Referring to LEGO bricks as legos hurts their trademark. The term could become generic which would allow MegaBloks to refer to their product as legos.

@Pubby8 ooooooh, thanks. what about "LEGO products" do you think, since we would ostensibly have DUPLO and etc on here.

@JoeWreschnig I wasn't asking you any further to explain that. I only said "what does that mean, I'm confused".

@JoeWreschnig It's turning a proper noun into a regular noun. If the word enters the english language then trademark doesn't hold up. That's why we have Kleenex tissues and Band Aid bandages.

@Joe it's probably the first time we have a zealot zealous enough to telltale to the copyright owner

Note, the problem with "LEGO Answers" seems to be that "Answers" can be taken as a verb, so "Unofficial LEGO Answers" may actually be OK. I've sent some of the suggestions to Jan to have a definite answer. Anything without "LEGO®" in it is bound to be OK, but I think it would be a bit sad.

"Brick Exchange" sounds like a market for bricks.

This shouldn't be a CW answer, we should have each option as a separate answer to vote on.
